How to animate a path from SwiftUI?
I know how to animate a single property like StrokeStart/StrokeEnd, or pairs of properties. I'm talking about what you can do from CoreAnimation: Create an animation that animates replacing one path with a different path with the same number of control points. Something like this:

I created that in Swift/UIKit with this project:
https://github.com/DuncanMC/RandomBlobs
That project uses CoreAnimation and creates a CABasicAnimation that builds a CAShapeLayer and replaces the path in the layer with a new path with the same number of control points.
I would expect SwiftUI to support the same ability using its Shape or Path objects, but have not figured out how to do that yet. (Yes, I know I could wrap a UIKit UIView for use in SwiftUI. I haven't done that yet, but I know it's possible. I'm looking for a native SwiftUI solution.)

The designated way to do this in SwiftUI is through Animatable. The idea is you declare some animatableData, that SwiftUI will set during each frame of the animation, interpolating between the start and end values.
animatableData needs to be a VectorArithmetic type. For this example, let's suppose the shape has 5 points, then animatableData would be representing a vector of 10 values. There is a built-in AnimatablePair that allows you to compose two VectorArithmetics together, but that's only composing two at a time.
Here is a type that can compose any number of VectorArithmetic types together
struct ComposedVectorArithmetic<each V>: VectorArithmetic where repeat each V: VectorArithmetic {
    
    var elements: (repeat each V)
    
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        .init(elements: (repeat (each lhs.elements) + (each rhs.elements)))
    }
    static func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        .init(elements: (repeat (each lhs.elements) - (each rhs.elements)))
    }
    
    mutating func scale(by rhs: Double) {
        elements = (repeat (each elements).scaled(by: rhs))
    }
    
    var magnitudeSquared: Double {
        var sum = 0.0
        for element in repeat each elements {
            sum += element.magnitudeSquared
        }
        return sum
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        for (a, b) in repeat (each lhs.elements, each rhs.elements) {
            if a != b {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    
    static var zero: Self {
        .init(elements: (repeat (each V).zero))
    }
}

extension ComposedVectorArithmetic: Sendable where repeat each V: Sendable {}

Then you can write such a Shape:
struct FivePointShape: View, Animatable {
    var points: FivePoints
    
    var animatableData: FivePoints {
        get { points }
        set { points = newValue }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Path { p in
            p.addLines([points.p1, points.p2, points.p3, points.p4, points.p5])
            p.closeSubpath()
        }
        .fill(.yellow)
    }
}

struct FivePointShape: Shape, Animatable {
    typealias AnimatableData = ComposedVectorArithmetic<UnitPoint,UnitPoint,UnitPoint,UnitPoint,UnitPoint>
    var points: AnimatableData
    
    var animatableData: AnimatableData {
        get { points }
        set { points = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { p in
            p.addLines([
                points.elements.0.point(in: rect),
                points.elements.1.point(in: rect),
                points.elements.2.point(in: rect),
                points.elements.3.point(in: rect),
                points.elements.4.point(in: rect),
            ])
            p.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}

extension UnitPoint: @retroactive AdditiveArithmetic, @retroactive VectorArithmetic {
    public mutating func scale(by rhs: Double) {
        x *= rhs
        y *= rhs
    }
    
    public var magnitudeSquared: Double {
        pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)
    }
    
    public static func +(lhs: UnitPoint, rhs: UnitPoint) -> UnitPoint {
        UnitPoint(x: lhs.x + rhs.x, y: lhs.y + rhs.y)
    }
    public static func -(lhs: UnitPoint, rhs: UnitPoint) -> UnitPoint {
        UnitPoint(x: lhs.x - rhs.x, y: lhs.y - rhs.y)
    }
    
    // this is for later...
    static func random() -> UnitPoint {
        .init(x: .random(in: 0...1), y: .random(in: 0...1))
    }

    func point(in rect: CGRect) -> CGPoint {
        .init(x: rect.minX + x * rect.width, y: rect.minY + y * rect.height)
    }
}

Usage:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var points = FivePointShape.AnimatableData.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            FivePointShape(points: points)
            Button("Animate!") {
                withAnimation {
                    points.elements = (
                        .random(),
                        .random(),
                        .random(),
                        .random(),
                        .random()
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Again, I've kept it simple here and just randomly choose a set of points to animate to, so most of the times the path intersects itself. In any case, you can see that each point animates as desired.

To do curves, you can create a type that represents a curve, and compose that using ComposedVectorArithmetic.
struct UnitBezier: VectorArithmetic {
    
    var points: ComposedVectorArithmetic<UnitPoint, UnitPoint, UnitPoint>
    
    var control1: UnitPoint {
        get { points.elements.0 }
        set { points.elements.0 = newValue }
    }
    var control2: UnitPoint {
        get { points.elements.1 }
        set { points.elements.1 = newValue }
    }
    var endPoint: UnitPoint {
        get { points.elements.2 }
        set {
            // for some reason swiftc cannot infer the type of 'points.elements' here, and crashes
            // so I have to write it in this ugly way...
            var elems: (UnitPoint, UnitPoint, UnitPoint) = points.elements
            elems.2 = newValue
            points.elements = elems
        }
    }
    
    init(control1: UnitPoint, control2: UnitPoint, endPoint: UnitPoint) {
        points = .init(elements: (control1, control2, endPoint))
    }
    
    init(points: ComposedVectorArithmetic<UnitPoint, UnitPoint, UnitPoint>) {
        self.points = points
    }
    
    mutating func scale(by rhs: Double) {
        points.scale(by: rhs)
    }
    
    var magnitudeSquared: Double {
        points.magnitudeSquared
    }
    
    static var zero: UnitBezier { .init(control1: .zero, control2: .zero, endPoint: .zero) }
    
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        .init(points: lhs.points + rhs.points)
    }
    static func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        .init(points: lhs.points - rhs.points)
    }
    
}

// example:
struct ThreeCurves: Shape, Animatable {
    typealias AnimatableData = ComposedVectorArithmetic<UnitPoint, UnitBezier, UnitBezier, UnitBezier>
    var points: AnimatableData
    
    var animatableData: AnimatableData {
        get { points }
        set { points = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { p in
            p.move(to: points.elements.0.point(in: rect))
            p.addCurve(
                to: points.elements.1.endPoint.point(in: rect),
                control1: points.elements.1.control1.point(in: rect),
                control2: points.elements.1.control2.point(in: rect)
            )
            p.addCurve(
                to: points.elements.2.endPoint.point(in: rect),
                control1: points.elements.2.control1.point(in: rect),
                control2: points.elements.2.control2.point(in: rect)
            )
            p.addCurve(
                to: points.elements.3.endPoint.point(in: rect),
                control1: points.elements.3.control1.point(in: rect),
                control2: points.elements.3.control2.point(in: rect)
            )
            p.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}


Thanks for the answer. That seems pretty unsatisfactory for a number of reasons: You can convert segments in a path from straight lines to Bézier curves and Core Animation animates the change smoothly. Having to build a separate structure for differing numbers of points is awful, and it is a lot of boilerplate code to write. (Not a critique of your answer, but of the current limitations of SwiftUI animation.)

Why don't the creators of SwiftUI treat a path as a single object and use CoreAnimation to do the heavy lifting to animate changes? That's what you do in Core Animation.

I don't see any way to represent curves vs straight lines using VectorArithmetic.

I guess you'd have to represent straight lines as Bézier curves with the middle control points along a straight line between the endpoints. But that wouldn't let you switch between quadratic and cubic Bézier curves like you can with CGPath CAAnimation.

@DuncanC I agree that SwiftUI makes this rather cumbersome, but I do think that curved lines can be somehow represented with vectors, and it is possible to switch between quadratic and cubic curves, because quadratic curves can be seen as a subset of cubic curves, where the 2 control points coincide. I’d imagine that’s how CA does it under the hood too. All animation will eventually boil down to interpolating numbers. There is no magic.

Accordding to the Wiki article on Bézier curves, you can create a quadratic Bézier curve using a Cubic curve where the control points are 2/3 rds of the way along a line segment between one of the endpoints and the quadratic curve's middle endpoint. (Not a cubic curve where the 2 middle endpoints match) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve#:~:text=A%20cubic%20Bézier%20curve%20%28yellow%29%20can%20be%20made,the%20quadratic%20curve%27s%20middle%20control%20point%20%28black%20rectangle%29., and search for the string "A cubic Bézier curve (yellow) can be made identical to a quadratic..."

Having to have a custom structure for each different count of vectors is fatal to a program that is intended to manage/animate arbitrary paths with any number of path segments.

I haven't studied Swift 6 or parameter Packs yet. I guess it's time to do so.

Even with Core Animation, the one restriction is that the starting and ending path have to have the same number of endpoints.

@DuncanC CA is CA and SwiftUI is SwiftUI. If you find doing it in Core Animation is easier (this is also my opinion), just do it in Core Animation.

I can make CA (Core Animation) sit up and dance. I'm trying to learn the SwiftUI way of doing things. While I'm learning, CA is always going to be easier.

@DuncanC you seem to think that SwiftUI is a replacement for Core Animation? It really isn’t, in the same way that a UITextView is not a replacement for Core Text.
